# Linux rm -rf * delete orders?

Tags: linux, shell, command, rm

I thought rm removes the files in alphabetically, but clearly it's not after my executation.

[image]

So, what 's the order of command rm executation?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161770/how-does-rm-r-go-about-recursively-removing-in-what-order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not `rm` itself providing the sorted nature, it's the shell expansion. If you were to type `rm *`, the *shell* would expand that to something like:

```
rm aaa bbb ccc
```

and `rm` would never even *see* a `*` argument. By the way, while I'm not certain that sorted behaviour is guaranteed for *all* shells, it certainly is for `bash`, as per the documentation:

> ... replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern.

The command `rm -rf *` is a slightly strange, hybrid case since, even if the shell sorts the `*` entries, that's still only for the first level of entries.

Hence `rm -rf *` may well expand to:

```
rm -rf aa_dir bb_dir cc_dir
```

but it's totally up to how `rm` works internally as to the order of processing of the entries *under* those directories though, obviously, it's a safe bet that all entries in a directory will be deleted before the directory itself.

More than likely it'll just be using `readdir()` or something similar, which will order things based on how they're stored in the directory "files" rather than some alphabetical ordering.

In any case, the order in which they're deleted probably shouldn't matter - they'll all eventually be deleted, assuming permissions allow.

Comment: Thanks!  it 's helpful! I googled a lot, there are many not detailed enough answers.